# Google Maps API v3 doesn't support "hl" param yet?

Tags: google-maps

As I tried "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&hl=ja" in  tag, the returned JavaScript content still shows en-US for "hl" param. It seems that v3 API doesn't support local language until now. Is it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Localization parameters has changed in the v3. You should read [the Localization documentation](http://code.google.com/intl/fr-FR/apis/maps/documentation/v3/basics.html#Localization).

Basically, instead of `hl`, you should use `language`. And there is also a new `region` setting. Everything is in the linked documentation.